# How can I remove app data from Google Play?

Tags: clash-of-clans

So I got a new phone, I logged to Clash of Clans and I accidentally logged to my Google Play Games through Google+. Sadly google saved me this lvl 1 base on Google Play. Now, when I tried to connect to google+ from my old phone (where I have a lvl 42 base) I get this message says: **"Do you want to load a lvl 1 Town Hall? Warning: progress in the current game will be lost."**

How can I overwrite the lvl 42 base instead of that lvl 1 base on my new phone?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you must delete all data in Settings>General>Apps>Clash of Clans then simply log in to the correct account. I use this method all the time so I can have 2 accounts. Tell me if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Answer no, then re-link from the level 42 game, it should warn you that it'll overwrite any progress you've made on your online copy (The level 1 one) and you can then save the level 42 over the top.

Comment: when I'm trying to log to google+ from my lvl 42 base - I get that message which if I'll click on "Load",  the level 42 game might get lost.